# How to set the placeholder positon of UITextView?

Tags: uitextview

I am using UITextView, i want put a placeholder in UITextView.
Because i can't set placeholder for a UITextView directly, so i use a third party lib: [SAMTextView](https://github.com/soffes/SAMTextView). But how can i put the placeholder postion in the middle of UITextView? Just like this picture.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that is a UITextView? It looks more like a UITextField.

Comment: I think it is a UITextView. i want input mutile lines, so i use UITextView.

Comment: But then how is this going to work? You cannot input into the middle of an empty text view. If the text view is empty you start at the start.